# Are separate tags for [geocoding] and [locator] needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have these two tags:

- [geocoding](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geocoding) with 631 questions and a tag wiki excerpt of:

> A GIS operation for converting street addresses into spatial data that
>   can be displayed as features on a map, usually by referencing address
>   information from a street segment data layer.

- [locator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locator) with 32 questions and a tag wiki excerpt of:

> A script/process for parsing a text-based location description, such
>   as a street address, and determining the geographic location by using
>   a reference dataset.

Do we need both?

[10 questions have been tagged with both](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geocoding+locator) suggesting there may be some confusion as to which to use when.